# How do I make my program in VB show the number of letters in a text box, into a tab box?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program whereby it takes text and 'encrypts' it. I managed to do the caeser cypher part, but another part was to get the string value in the encrypted text, and display the number of characters in it. I decided to get the text from a text box, and display it in a tabcontrol box. What would be the code to get the values from the textbox, list what they are, and how many times they appear in the text box?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

use this code below; will gets you the character length in your textbox
TextBox1.TextLength

Comment: for example like this; Label1.Text = TextBox1.TextLength

Comment: How would I incorporate this? Sorry, I'm a noob :p

Comment: lol its okay just try my code with label and textbox you will get it :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't read your comment properly. My Bad. However, how would i get said label to display the frequency of the characters in TextBox1?

Comment: what do you mean by frequency?

Comment: Textbox1.TextLength will return the number of _characters_ in the textbox but not necessarily the number of _letters_

Comment: import regex put this line before anything in the page

    **Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions**

and use this code to make a try that the code Works;

    **MsgBox(Regex.Replace(Textbox1.Text, "[^aA-zZ]", "").Length)**